# How to combine Access 2010 databases and keep relationships

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working on an existing MS Access 2010 application that has 9 separate .accdb files.  7 of these databases comprise a single local table and then several linked tables with which the one local table has foreign key relationships.  There is also a database with just 15 local tables and finally a database with the forms/queries and links to all the other tables in all the other databases.

What I would like to end up with is one "back end" .accdb file with all the tables stored locally and one "front-end" .accdb that holds the forms/queries with links to the tables.

My specific question is how to combine the various data holding .accdb files into one.  Everything I've tried so far (Importing, converting to local) results in errors or relationships being lost.

A simplified example is:

```
Database 1 has
   Local Table A
   Linked Table B
   Linked Table C
   Linked Table D

 Table A has relationships with B, C, D

Database 2 has 
   Local Table B
   Linked Table C
   Linked Table D
   Linked Table E

 Table B has relationships with C, D, E

Database 3 has 
   Local Tables C, D, E
```

I'd like to end up with a single back-end Db:

```
Database Z
   Local Tables A, B, C, D, E with all relationships intact.
```

Is this doable?  Any advice greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: So External Data \ Import on Ribbon does not work? By default it imports relationships and retains linked table as linked objects (which you can run make-table queries into local tables).

Comment: It works but the result can be two versions of some tables, one local and one linked.  I was hoping that the process would be intelligent enough to detect that an imported linked table points to a local table in the destination database and so replace the linked table with the local equivalent in imported relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility might be to create all the tables locally in your final back-end database making sure to *uncheck* relationships in the Import Objects dialog (under the Options >> menu).

Then add this code from Microsoft (it's old, but should still work): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210302.  Use it to import the relationships only from each of the separate front-end databases.

Note that if any relationships have the same name they will fail to import.

Comment: Thanks - interesting idea.  Not sure this would work for me "as is" because the imported relationships would still use linked tables even though the object of those links were in the current db. 

However, I could import all back-end databases, including relationships, into one db and modify the VBA code to "fix" each relationship.  i.e. where the relationship is with a linked table that points to a local table in the current db, modify the relationship to use the local version.  At the end, delete the linked tables.   I'll post again if I try this and it works.

Comment: @Grayman If it helps any I tried importing all tables as local to one db.  Then the import relationship routine worked even though the referenced db had one table as linked.  I think as long as the name is the same it doesn't care, but I'm not sure.  Hope one of these methods works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately I had to do what I suggested earlier.  i.e. import all tables and relationships into one back-end db.  The relationships were successfully imported but were with linked tables instead of the local.  I used VBA code to find these relationships, "clone" them and modify to use the local table.  The original relationships then had to be removed.